# Why isn't the new "postgres" user I created showing up in User Accounts?

Tags: users, postgresql

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron 1545, then downloaded & installed all the latest updates.  Now when I create a new user ***postgres*** in the "User Accounts..." window, it creates the account, but it's not listed in the User Accounts window.  Since it's not listed, I am not able to create a password or "enable" the account so they can login.

I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04 thinking there might have been a bug during installation, but I got the same thing again.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Check the used id. If it is under 500 it will not show up. Get an UID above 500 and it will.

Comment: uid=1001 and it still doesn't show up.  I also tried this on a Dell Vostro 220 (desktop) - same thing.

Comment: gah, figured it out... any user named "postgres" is automatically hidden by Ubuntu.  Apparently, Ubuntu reserves this username for PostgreSQL.  Any other username will work.  :-P

Comment: oh? that's new to me :D Add it in as an anwser @ken You get some rep and accepting it will tell the AU bot not to kick this up every now and then ;)

Comment: Glad you got it solved.  Other than the problem with that particular user name, remember that whenever the gui won't cooperate, you can do just about anything from the command line in a terminal and you'll get much better feedback when something goes wrong.  guis are nice, but when you already know what you want to do, the command line is often faster and easier.

Comment: If it weren't a Dell iwth Intel architecture, one could think that it looks exactly like the effects of a bug, which affects other accountsservice on other architectures like ARM or PPC -- described in the answer http://askubuntu.com/a/150950/19753 .

Comment: Ken, please take a moment to come back and accept the answer (or add your own and accept it), so that the question is marked closed and future readers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

As you found out, Ubuntu reserves the `postgres` user for maintenance (upgrades, backups, etc.) and other internal tasks, which require that this "user" be able to login without a password. Consequently, `postgres` is *hidden* from the User Accounts list, even if you create that user manually.

To allow local PSQL connections with a password, you can use the `createuser` utility and grant that user admin privileges.